# How to display indoor.shp file in TileMill

Tags: osmdroid, mapbox, tilemill

I make indoor map with JOSM (.osm format) then i sucessfully convert them in to shapefile(.shp format). I want to convert them in to MBTiles format in order to display andorid application by using TileMill. When i upload my shp file in TileMill project , i cant see my map. Is there a way to show it? Thank you.

Here is my .shp file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i081sh9pgof7f0z/indoorshpfile.rar)

```
Map {
  background-color: #b8dee6;
}

#countries {
  ::outline {
    line-color: #85c5d3;
    line-width: 2;
    line-join: round;
  }
  polygon-fill: #fff;
}

#polygon.poly {
  line-color:#594;
  line-width:0.5;
  polygon-opacity:1;
  polygon-fill:#ae8;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JOSM to shp to MBTiles... For an indoor map... It seems a little bit complicated.

I imagine that your map is made of lines and polygons?

I could suggest that you (re)build your indoor map from scratch as a KML file (with Google Earth, or ArcGIS, or even with Google Maps).

Then you will be able to load this KML directly on an Android device:

- either with Google Earth for Android
- or with [OSMNavigator](http://osmbonuspack.googlecode.com/svn/BonusPackDownloads/OSMNavigator_v4.3.apk) application (based on OSMBonusPack+osmdroid)
- or by writing your own application using OSMBonusPack+osmdroid libs.

Comment: but Google not support my country for indoor map. Yes but indoor josm and osm has not tool about indoor map that.They are not shows rooms. Finally I decided render jpg :S so difficult for me all of them